# Why doesn't initialize appear as a method when I call on the instance methods of a class?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a blog post on how almost everything is an object in Ruby, and I'm trying to show this through the following example:

```
class CoolBeans
  attr_accessor :beans

  def initialize
    @bean = []
  end

  def count_beans
    @beans.count
  end 

end
```

So from looking at the class we can tell it has 4 methods(unless of course, I'm wrong):

1. It can initialize a default empty array of beans when a new instance is created
2. It can count how many beans it has
3. It can read how many beans it had (through the `attr_accessor`)
4. It can write(or add) more beans to the empty array (also through the `attr_accessor`)

However, when I ask the class itself what instance methods it has, I don't see the default `initialize` method:

```
CoolBeans.new.class.instance_methods
# => [:beans, :beans=, :count_beans, :lm, :lim, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :to_s, :inspect, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method, :singleton_method, :define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]
```

Does this mean that the initialize method is not an instance method?  If not, why isn't it showing up as a method available to the class `CoolBeans`?

Comment: you have error in instance variable. must be `@beans` not `@bean`

Comment: Regarding 3 and 4: to be precise, `attr_accessor` has nothing to do with inspecting or manipulating the array. It creates an instance method `beans` that returns the object assigned to `@beans` and another instance method `beans=` that assigns a new object to `@beans`.

Comment: thanks--I'll change that.

Comment: @Becca nit-picking, but `beans` doesn't return the object**s** (as you say in your blog), it returns the object (singular), i.e. the array. This allows you to send messages to the array, like `count` or `<<`. You couldn't do that, if it would return a bunch of objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) returns an array of **public** and **protected** methods. However, `initialize` is automatically **private** <sup>[ref](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/Object.html)</sup>.

```
CoolBeans.private_instance_methods
# => [:initialize, :default_src_encoding, :irb_binding, :initialize_copy, :initialize_dup, :initialize_clone, :sprintf, :format, :Integer, :Float, :String, :Array, :Hash, :warn, :raise, :fail, :global_variables, :__method__, :__callee__, :__dir__, :eval, :local_variables, :iterator?, :block_given?, :catch, :throw, :loop, :respond_to_missing?, :trace_var, :untrace_var, :at_exit, :syscall, :open, :printf, :print, :putc, :puts, :gets, :readline, :select, :readlines, :`, :p, :test, :srand, :rand, :trap, :load, :require, :require_relative, :autoload, :autoload?, :proc, :lambda, :binding, :caller, :caller_locations, :exec, :fork, :exit!, :system, :spawn, :sleep, :exit, :abort, :Rational, :Complex, :set_trace_func, :gem, :gem_original_require, :singleton_method_added, :singleton_method_removed, :singleton_method_undefined, :method_missing]
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  If you want, check out my blog at http://beccaades.github.io/blog/2015/09/10/back-to-basics-how-everything-really-is-an-object-in-ruby/

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated :)

Comment: When I pass in the value false, I don't get back any methods at all...is there a way to exclude the inherited methods but keep the instance methods?

Comment: @Becca - its a well written blog!

Comment: @Becca sorry, I was confusing `#methods` with [`#instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods). Passing `false` to the latter excludes inherited methods. `method` on the other hand returns singleton methods when you pass `false`. I've deleted my previous comment, it is misleading.

Comment: `initialize` isn't *always* private, it is *by default* private. You can make it public if you want.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What [the doc](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/Object.html) says is: *the method named `initialize`automatically falls under private visibility.*  Plus, it seems I can't [make it public](http://ideone.com/aLY8GY), could you explain more?

Comment: Like I said, it is private by default when you define it, you have to explicitly make it public: `class Foo; public def initialize; end end; Foo.public_instance_methods.include?(:initialize) # => true`